# PHP: Checking code failure

Tags: php, debugging, message

I wrote a login page using this nice tut:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL
Everything works great locally.

I uploaded the code to a remote server and over there registration works fine (registration info
is written correctly in the DB), but i can't log-in. On of the functions responsible for checking log-in information returns `false`.

**MY QUESTION:**
If only `index.php` includes HTML code, and all other files are pure PHP\JS,
what would be a good way to check what function returns `false`?

Is there a way to show some message right before the `return false` statements in all PHP functions?

Thank you!

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); // place these code at top of the php page, it will show errors, but it will not show your logic mistakes

Comment: `display_errors` won't break where statements only `return false` though.

Comment: in the old days before time, when we had no debug avaliable for PHP all we had was echo. Place some echos to display what is going on with your code.

Comment: even though i'm not redirecting to the php files? (i stay in index.php the whole time)

Comment: uacaman, sorry for reasking, i didn't quite get it. Will it work if im not redirecting to the file that has the php functions for checking the login?